# Cant read the string completely from the input stream

Tags: java, android, bufferedreader

I have been facing issues lately with the BufferedReader. It reads from the stream partially (Partially in the sense that it reads from the input stream less than what the server actually wrote in the output stream. The response has many lines). Below is the code

```
while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null){ //<- Reads partially
                buffer.append(inputLine); 
              // Buffer Is an object of StringBuffer
               // And in is bufferedreader.
}
```

I searched about this on Google and found that this could be because of the lapse between the server and client while reading and writing. So i tried the below code then.

```
            int counter =0;
            while(counter <5){
                while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null){
                    buffer.append(inputLine);
                    counter = 0;
                }
                counter++;

                if(counter==4){
                    try {
                        Thread.sleep(1000);
                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            }
```

Still no improvement. I am using Google's api text search to make some query which returns a large amount of text. But the weird thing is that it always returns response of the same length. I realized this when I read this post

http://tiku.io/questions/4155487/android-httpget-incomplete-response-bufferedreader

In the above link (3rd answer), he mentioned that this is not an issue with the buffered reader but that Java String has some limitation. Hard to believe! Can this be the reason? technically speaking length of the string returns an integer, So the max length of the String can't be anything more than 2^32-1(More than efficient, but yeah its not an actual bound for string. But the response is not so huge that it will run out of memory. And no OutOfMemory Exception too). So can anyone tell what is the actual issue here ?

Sample partial response read by the application

```
{   "html_attributions" : [      "Listings by \u003ca href=\"http://www.indiacom.com/\"\u003eIndiacom Yellow Pages\u003c/a\u003e"   ],   "next_page_token" : "CuQB3QAAAA9LWxl0Zihy1r0NqXIJ8MsCZ9JVHrvm13-PtAz_6E59zAcnd7fKnEVg8LXgm30ACPG2sBUqx2_hGIxuZXpE4phQBR_SB8JdTJFJKTJ7VKoQNU9iQXPbS-0MAxW2lqrsJzAj7ZLKnlwYVXEYi7Vcw-qskrJweeJKU0mtz1s1NgkrwjPMoi78VHuw3-i79xTlQIwFCmHpNyGXiG4cAWXm4T8uBqERZZ7p3SDv-dmoqZceLlWYzZheRcllGEtkfTbCAVwLCw168mbM_mzNcxWbx-96GyQIjlSIYiyJuxM6_S5xEhC3ekHSAg-E3fVFuvqIiEfFGhR9SpyAw0_t-FAir6mJn9ElV3vAnA",   "results" : [      {         "formatted_address" : "No. 313, Mettupalayam Road, Saibaba Koil, Coimbatore, Tamil Nadu 641043, India",         "geometry" : {            "location" : {               "lat" : 11.026208,               "lng" : 76.95259799999999            }         },         "icon" : "http://maps.gstatic.com/mapfiles/place_api/icons/generic_business-71.png",         "id" : "ef736016c44cf960d4c7d4d9d32ac221c8255f5a",         "name" : "Ganga Hospital",         "place_id" : "ChIJ9-xr2e9YqDsRLnG40S1Ndrk",         "rating" : 4.4,         "reference" : "CoQBcQAAANcLCLGKHLEbTSwQdcbhRiJcrtKJqJbl9H5umesRvtlXWCYUwsTxbvVRHfaVh-l7RRje1HVsuklQ_XGnmc7OXHW4ZUfPYIBIH6tB5XLs6_5lj9W9hT6Q1EH4zK5k7Cbf6Wu52qFyj93CWLmuj5qeoLwgptNCWf3-ujmbVDrcHDLyEhD-2Bja75Fa8FeLBJbY032GGhSuCw2uExbtV_YBx-3pyRCizTalXA",         "types" : [ "hospital", "establishment" ]      },      {         "formatted_address" : "Govt Arts College Road, Gopalapuram, Coimbatore, Tamil Nadu 641018, India",         "geometry" : {            "location" : {               "lat" : 11.000514,               "lng" : 76.971526            }         },         "icon" : "http://maps.gstatic.com/mapfiles/place_api/icons/generic_business-71.png",         "id" : "d6f82ccc732044cc3deb9fa6c5a4283707cd03f1",         "name" : "KG Hospital",         "place_id" : "ChIJAQBAtaVZqDsRtFzd-7QKtpA",         "rating" : 3.7,         "reference" : "CnRuAAAAmpE68INB08dOsxIyKg_Ys9qaZjIjelNkA32E4zu963JCILPN94cTM_7b5-s6lp9ElnmwcMyO689bsn_1ax40Y_VI8WiXkk65mHAqUEoh7awcEEtgx-HjI3rLdZPEXDTjRBj-7SohkyH-s-QogvHKxxIQ3lAGHhT_HyZV-Yo8W0f8RxoUv8GPvTTXu8SFUawpMgSSEE8C0BA",         "types" : [ "hospital", "establishment" ]      },      {         "formatted_address" : "Nethaji Road,Pappanaickenpalayam, Coimbatore, Tamil Nadu 641037, India",         "geometry" : {            "location" : {               "lat" : 11.01277,               "lng" : 76.980508            }         },         "icon" : "http://maps.gstatic.com/mapfiles/place_api/icons/generic_business-71.png",         "id" : "7e57fe692d9273faba387bfbf10e0d6ad48dd893",         "name" : "G Kuppuswamy Naidu Memorial Hospital",         "photos" : [            {               "height" : 935,               "html_attributions" : [],               "photo_reference" : "CnRnAAAAhUxLjdksHg289yJS08LGuNefM_CDKjCYHbLcVItrUnFNylD7YpgFPVyGSjg3FOADXhrz-nXkEC82gBLyzOIuMq0xXJapoJzmtq9rZmVFaUz9iaM33VxRt9qY2oP46AXwmi0g2ic67Um7iYNbQb1bcBIQqjM9-sR6kM-WeVRKB5wljhoUcDt52QaV_U6D8KGhysYTdUq7yno",               "width" : 1809            }         ],         "place_id" : "ChIJH8pncLNZqDsRJE3drBfyqC4",         "rating" : 4.3,         "reference" : "CpQBhgAAAIYMMgOuddpbNbU2OnTafr2WmqwLoy9VMe1JCgAdcpv84bwHCdZLDmsD0cDsDVfkOxxFnBchCca-O8zTvFl6ZqWPLIG9Sia7H6fpFQl-8BqM9na9FKiY-6M0OgdPn493nseIRidQGZAz8h121zKb4ks--IvdpSn3khR6G3-j6mrod9DSSfa5MwDIjTGxJYaDzBIQPMJyhDwCM9ASoRtBXFXdhRoUtSURW5KmhN9n6NcwjMJObp4on2w",         "types" : [ "hospital", "health", "establishment" ]      },      {         "formatted_address" : "No. 120, West Periasamy Road, R.S.Puram, Coimbatore, Tamil Nadu 641002, India",         "geometry" : {            "location" : {               "lat" : 11.013005,               "lng" : 76.948144            }         },         "icon" : "http://maps.gstatic.com/mapfiles/place_api/icons/generic_business-71.png",         "id" : "1fc1beb232ca7fb02555df76889cad33eb20d060",         "name" : "Rao Hospital",         "place_id" : "ChIJIzoxVRxZqDsRF7rY3dvXP5o",         "reference" : "CnRvAAAA7_4DD-Df4zKXujSMTj-aEkR_gazKz__hfBPqYJOJmMHAbX-IaaeWNDc6e-6YW
```

Length of the partial read response varies between 19,000 - 20000.

Comment: Instead of appending to a buffer - write (append) the line into a file and after you finish reading/writing - check the size of that file and you'll have your answer. As a sidenote, I already ran into a scenario where size was indeed the problem.

Comment: It doesn't help that we don't know what you're reading from, how much is read, what the encoding is, etc. I would ignore that "size limit of string" part - that sounds completely bogus to me.

Comment: @JonSkeet It is an HTTP response form the Google's Places API which is in JSON format. I will update the length of the that is read.

Comment: A BufferedReader's readLine returns after it has read one (and only one) line or sensed eof. So what do you mean by "Reads partially"? Explain, please!

Comment: @laune Have Edited my question.

Comment: So why don't you simply wait for line after line? The HTTP protocol defines what to expect: length in the header or otherwise.

Comment: @laune I tried that. My second modified coded tried waiting for 5 secs(instead of 1 sec, which is the code posted in my question), still the same output. when i tried the same thing in browser, got the whole response in 1 sec.

Comment: Probably there is no requirement why the sender of that JSON stuff should send it in multiple lines (as in CRLF terminated). So, doing a readLine is rather wobbly anyway. I'm not sure what the BufferedReader does if the last line is never terminated.

Comment: @laune  It appears to me that its a memory issue :/ . I tried to append something more to the string it just does not happen. Neither it throws any exception .

Comment: Append to the StringBuffer you mean? That shouldn't be baffled by anything below 1M

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/69075/discussion-between-ashwin-surana-and-laune).